# Center part title in Lyx

Tags: formatting, lyx

How can I, in tex code or directly in the Lyx GUI, put the part title in the center.

e.g. instead of this:

```
Part I

Introduction and Background theory
```

this:

```
              Part I

   Introduction and Background theory
```

MWE:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.1.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}


\part{Test abcabc}

body text

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the option to create a centered environment? E.g. `\begin{center}Part I ...\end{center}` or the switch `\centering`?
That would be for how to center things in TeX. Whether the LyX GUI offers that option I don't know, but I would assume so.
Sent from my phone. If needed a more detailed explanation with examples could be provided.

I see now. You could use

```
 % Preview source code

%% LyX 2.1.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\partfont{\centering}
\begin{document}
\part{Test abcabc}
body text
\end{document}
```

Comment: This has no effect

Comment: Would you be so kind and give us a MWE example of your code? I don't use LyX but from what I know I don't see why that shouldn't work.

Comment: Done. See updated post.

Comment: @Tim I updated my answer accordingly