# How to center part,section,... (LyX)

Tags: lyx, sections-paragraphs

How Can I center a *part* or a *section* in LyX?
I saw this question - [Center part title in Lyx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248176/center-part-title-in-lyx) - but I want to know to do it every time without write any part, section,... `\begin{center}...\end{center}`

It is possible?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you try using `\sectionfont{\centering}` and `\subsectionfont{\centering}` to center the section and subsection headings?

Comment: @leandriis - it's doesn't recognize it.. :-(

Answer (score 1):

In LyX itself, I don't know, but you can delve into the underlying code and  write in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\part}{\centering}
\titleformat*{\section}{\centering}
```

For more  complex changes you'll have to use the `\titleformat` command (without a star), which has 4 mandatory and 1 optional arguments.

*Edit*:  Here is an ‘advanced’ code:

```
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\filcenter\huge\bfseries}{\partname \thepart}{4ex} {}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\filcenter\LARGE\bfseries} {\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
```

Comment: I think the only LyX-specific instruction would be to put the above commands in Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble

Comment: It's give an error. it says: _Package titlesec Error: Not allowed in `easy' settings._ What can I do?

Comment: Could you post  a full compilable code  producing this error? I tested this solution with a minimal code before posting, so probably there's something else which is not compatible with this code.

Comment: @Bernard - Sure! this is the error: https://anotepad.com/notes/j2tg7h

Comment: And here is the full code of the document - https://anotepad.com/notes/47bsmc

Comment: @heblyx: Unfortunately, I cannot test, as I don't have the required fonts. You can try the *‘advanced settings’*: replace my suggestion in he preamble with the ‘advanced code’ in my edit. The parameters used in this code can be adapted to fulfil your needs. Last point: I think you should use `utf8` input encoding.

Comment: @Bernard - Still doesn't work :(